# dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" taking too long to execute nearly 30-40 minutes in local or Azure pipeline coverlet-coverage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, xunit, coverlet

I have a .net6 application with the below dependencies

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Abp.MemoryDb" Version="6.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite" Version="5.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="6.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="6.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.extensibility.execution" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Shouldly" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NSubstitute" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.2.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

When I run the command command without code coverage

```
dotnet test
```

The execution doesn't take too long, however with the below command it goes upto 40-50 minutes in local as well as in the Azure pipeline.

```
dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"
```

Comment: See https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/issues/1192